# android EMFILE (Too many open files)

Tags: android, file

I implemented a file cache to load small images for a long grid view. After scrolling a while, I get a lot of `libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EMFILE (Too many open files)`

How do I avoid this? This is the code to read one bitmap:

```
File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), cacheDir);
File file = new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), fileName);

if (!file.exists()) {
    return null;
}

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString());
```

This is to save one bitmap:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileUri);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any chance your close() call isn't being reached due to an exception?  I generally code like this:

```
try {
  new FileOutputStream(fileUri);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
  outputStream.flush();
} finally {
  try {
    outputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
    // ignore exceptions generated by close()
  }
}
```

I couldn't see anything obviously wrong with the first code fragment.

Comment: Just an update: Apache Commons has a [closeQuietly()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable)) utility which will close a Closeable and swallow the exception. I find this so useful that even when Apache Commons isn't available, I [roll my own](http://www.efalk.org/Docs/Java/techniques.html#Close_Quietly)